# USB Receiver switch between two PCs

Tags: usb, switches, diy, dpdt, cable-assemblies

I use two desktop PCs and one set of wireless keyboard and mouse (Logitech with the 2.4 GHz Receiver). I got tired of plugging and unplugging the receiver so I took two old usb cables, a usb socket and a dpdt switch to make a  usb switch. Unfortunately neither pc will recognize the receiver when I plug it into my DIY switch. I have never done something like this so perhaps I’m missing something very fundamental. I’m hoping someone here has experience with home projects like these and may be able to tell me where I went wrong...[image: picture to clarify]

Comment: First question : does the receiver and the PC USB ports still work? Depending on if PCs have ground connections between them or not via other wiring like mains plug or monitor, omitting the ground wire may have done damage. Also USB is usually done with impedance controlled twisted pair cable, so trying to get it work via two separate wires may not work. Did you verify that both cables use same color coding or did you just assume it and connected by color?

Comment: The receiver by it self still works on both PCs. The usb cables I used came from the same set and have the same color coding. I connected Ground and VCC from the blue cable directly to the socket, just so I wouldn’t have to use 2 switches. On the white cable I just tied them off. Since both PCs are always running I figured that wouldn’t be a problem.

Comment: Yes but you are still missing the ground connection. If you had no other ground connection between PCs and one of the PCs was grounded and one of them ungrounded, you could have ended up with damaged USB ports and devices. Forunately, it did not happen.

Comment: Thank you still. I’ll try to start over and I’ll definitely add another switch for the VCC and Ground wires, although I’m starting to realize it will be even more complicated than that.

Comment: You can get 3 pole and 4 pole switches.  With them, you would only need one switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, yes, you missed something important.

USB uses fast digital signals. How fast depends on which version of USB (Low Speed, Full Speed, High Speed, Super speed) but they vary from very quite fast to ludicrously fast.

Fast signals need special care when laying out PCBs, or making cables.  This is a complicated subject, so I'm not going to try to explain it fully here, but you will need to use a carefully designed PCB to do something like this. Even if you can get that right, a basic mechanical switch could still cause problems. It will help if you can fool the devices into using USB low speed, as that will be more tolerant of imperfect cables/traces.

There are a couple of other things here which aren't great too, but which might not stop it working.  It looks like you're only switching the digital lines, not power and ground.  Differences in ground potential between the two host devices could cause problems, so it would be better to switch those too. Also there is supposed to be a strict order for connecting pins for USB: ground and power, then the digital lines.  Disconnection should be the reverse. Doing them in the wrong order has a chance of breaking things.

All in all, USB is a very tricky bus to work with. The good news is that there are some special ICs out there which will do what you want, but even then, laying out the PCB will be tricky.

Comment: Thanks @JackB. I appreciate all the advice! I’ll try to find information on how to lay out a PCB that’ll make it work. Hopefully I’ll be posting a pic of a functional device next time.                    PS: Now I understand why I couldn’t find a device like that on Amazon 

Comment: @Eigenvalue why not? They seem to cost about $19. There is almost no reason to build this unless you are determined that you can build and it will work safely.

Comment: I found it. I thought they were just standard hubs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure USB keyboards and mice already use low speed; they certainly don't use any more than full speed, which is still slow enough that you can get away with not worrying about trace impedance and stuff. Still, even if these cables aren't too sloppy (they probably are) all the other points you made still stand.

Answer (score 1):

Your switch has only two poles, for D+ and D- I assume. For a PC to recognise new connection (after disconnect/loss of communication), the VBUS also heeds to be switched and needs to go through zero voltage state. And, of course, ground needs to be connected all the time. The VBUS toggle will ensure that there will be another connect event, and also that the RF dongle will assume its default state and will be responsive to standard enumeration process.

Logitech RF dongles use FS (12 Mbps) mode, relatively slow, so a mechanical swich will likely do the job (if you take a better care of your loose wires, making them qute shorter).

Comment: Thank you, I'll make the cables shorter and I'll work on my soldering skills, this is the first time I've attempted a project like this. Would it be better if I used a 4 pole switch to toggle everything or a 3 pole and leave the ground connected all the time?

Comment: @Eigenvalue, you will have less trouble if you keep ground wire connection across your switch.